# Spring Boot Content type 'text/plain' not supported in POST request in terminal

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, post, hashmap

I have an application in spring boot. I created a post request to accept a string and to spit out a JSON in a text file. I am using @RequestBody as a Map. I'm not sure if I am utilizing that properly and that is the reason I am getting the error?

When I try to do

```
curl -d "ncs|56-2629193|1972-03-28|20190218|77067|6208|3209440|self|-123|-123|-123|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0"
 -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' 'http://localhost:9119/prediction'
```

It gives me this error

```
status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Content type 'text/plain' not supported","path":"/prediction"
```

This is my controller class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Validated
@RestController
public class MockController {

    @Autowired
    MockEndPoint mockendpoint;
    @Autowired
    MockConfig mockconfig;

    String w;
    String x;
    String y;
    String z;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "hello!";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/prediction", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json"},consumes= "text/html")
    public ResponseEntity<String> payloader1(@RequestBody HashMap<String,String> params ) throws IOException{

        params = mockconfig.getHashmap();

        if(params.containsKey(mockconfig.input1))
            w  = mockconfig.input1;
            String[] a = w.split("\\|");
            if (a.length == 18) 
        {
                return ResponseEntity.ok(params.get(mockconfig.input1)); 
        }
        else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Inccorect payload amount(18 parameters required");
        }



    }


}
```

This is my endpoint class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;

@Configuration
public class MockEndPoint {





    @Bean
    public String Payload1() throws IOException {
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("src/test/resources/Payload1.txt");
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        return content;
    }


    @Bean
    public String Payload2() throws IOException {
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("src/test/resources/Payload2.txt");
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        return content;
    }
    @Bean
    public String Payload3() throws IOException {
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("src/test/resources/Payload3.txt");
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        return content;
    }
    @Bean
    public String Payload4() throws IOException {
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("src/test/resources/Payload4.txt");
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        return content;
    }


    }
```

This is my config class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MockConfig {

    @Autowired
    MockEndPoint mockendpoint;

    String input1 = "ncs|56-2629193|1972-03-28|20190218|77067|6208|3209440|self|-123|-123|-123|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0";
    String input2 = "ncp|56-2629193|1955-11-28|20181213|73630|6404|182232|self|-123|-123|-123|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|33.35";
    String input3 = "ncp|56-2629193|1955-11-28|20190103|73630|6404|182232|self|-123|-123|-123|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|33.35";
    String input4 = "ncp|56-2629193|1955-11-28|20190213|73700|6404|182232|self|-123|-123|-123|0.0|20.0|325.0|0.0|0.0|269.28|269.28";







    public HashMap<String,String> getHashmap() throws IOException {
        HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put(input1,mockendpoint.Payload1());
        hm.put(input2,mockendpoint.Payload2());
        hm.put(input3,mockendpoint.Payload3());
        hm.put(input4,mockendpoint.Payload4());
        return hm;
    }

}
```

Comment: `@RequestBody` should be string type right?

Comment: Would I have to create a hash map separately then from the requestBody?

Comment: yes, create `HashMap` separately from that string

Comment: In curl why don't you put -X POST? And the request payload does nor look like of type Map that you are expecting in controller method. What is the error you are getting after making it texr/ plain?

Comment: @schooner_101 may I know why you changed the accepted answer? And why my answer does not solve your problem?

Comment: @fivelements I can't change the payload to JSON due to client standards. and ruhul  s answer fixed it by changing it to plain in my code

Comment: @schooner_101 did not I mention this in my answer: `The text/plain content won't be converted to Map by any converter. Otherwise, take request body as String and internally convert it to Map in your code.`

Comment: @fiveelements you have a point. changed answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please modify a couple of things:

- In case you expect a `Map` in the request body, you need to have `consumes` content type something other than `text/plain` like `application/json`. The `text/plain` content won't be converted to `Map` by any converter. Otherwise, take request body as `String` and internally convert it to `Map` in your code.
- In curl request add `-X POST`. Also, make the payload structure JSON key value pairs.

You are getting 405 error code due to text content in payload and expected request as `Map` data type. To confirm this, just remove the request body `Map` and see whether your API is hit. And then follow the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

You provide  `-H 'Content-Type: text/plain'` in **request** and wrote `consumes= "text/html"` in controller. Either make those two identical. After that, you should also change the data type `HashMap<String,String> params` to **String**. As you are passing those data as `text/plain`